# Mostrar daterangepicker "inline" dentro de un div, sin desplegable

Tags: jquery, html5, datepicker, daterangepicker

estoy haciendo un filtrado en un listado y me gustaría incluir el calendario con posibilidad de seleccionar un rango de fechas como me facilita daterangepicker en la columna de la izquierda como os muestro a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he encontrado ninguna opción para mantener el calendario estático en esta columna, siempre depende de un desplegable o un input que abre el calendario. 
He visto este link donde aparece estático colgando de un input "https://codepen.io/mindaugasvaiciulis/pen/pNboBJ" pero no es lo que busco.

He visto otros plugins como datepicker con los que si que se puede mantener el calendario estático pero no me da la opción de seleccionar un rango de fechas.

¿Alguno me puede decir si existe algún plugin con el que pueda seleccionar un rango de fecha y poner el calendario tal y como aparece en el ejemplo que os he adjuntado?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

[UPDATE]

Adjunto mi código y la prueba que he realizado con la sugerencia de David:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary filter-date-picker">
    Fecha
</a>
<div class="calendar-box"></div>
```

Y aquí el código javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filter-date-picker').daterangepicker({
            "locale": {
                "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
                "separator": " - ",
                "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
                "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
                "fromLabel": "Desde",
                "toLabel": "Hasta",
                "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
                "daysOfWeek": [
                    "Lu",
                    "Ma",
                    "Mi",
                    "Ju",
                    "Vi",
                    "Sa",
                    "Do"
                ],
                "monthNames": [
                    "Enero",
                    "Febrero",
                    "Marzo",
                    "Abril",
                    "Mayo",
                    "Junio",
                    "Julio",
                    "Agosto",
                    "Septiembre",
                    "Octubre",
                    "Noviembre",
                    "Diciembre"
                ],
                "firstDay": 0
            },
             // opens: 'left'
        }, function(start, end, label) {
            $(".filter-date-picker").html(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY')+" <i class='fas fa-minus'></i> "+end.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
        });


        $(".filter-date-picker").toggle(function() {
            $(".calendar-box").datepicker("show");
        }, function() {
            $(".calendar-box").datepicker("hide");
        });
```

El caso es que despues de implementar esto, directamente el div "filter-date-picker" desaparece.

Antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código HTML + Javascript?

Comment: @Kiko_L he actualizado la respuesta con el código.

Comment: En la función toogle, coloca "show" en donde dice "hide", es decir que muestre antes de seleccionar y que muestre luego de seleccionar.

Comment: @DavidDavila , Si te refieres a poner en los dos casos show, es lo que he hecho y sigue desapareciendo: 
`$(".filter-date-picker").toggle(function() {
            $(".calendar-box").datepicker("show");
        }, function() {
            $(".calendar-box").datepicker("show");
        });`

Comment: @DavidDavila Ahora que me fijo, el problema es que yo estoy utilizando "daterangepicker" y no "datepicker", por lo que este código no me va a funcionar. Pero muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el creador del plugin no existe una forma de mostrarlo inline por defecto:

> Hi Dan,
>
> Is there a configuration option to have the calendar appear "inline".
>   I would like to use the calendar without the input box ("always
>   visible") ?
>
> > > Dan Mod   No

Aquí te dejo un apaño que podrías hacer. La idea es mostrarlo siempre al inicio con

```
$('.calendar-box').data('daterangepicker').show();
```

Y a continuación *resetear* la función `hide()` para que no haga nada (así nunca oculta el calendario)

```
$('.calendar-box').data('daterangepicker').hide = function () { };
```

Además he quitado el `<a>` y he dejado sólo el `div .calendar-box` para que muestre ahí el calendario

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.calendar-box').daterangepicker({
        "locale": {
            "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
            "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
            "fromLabel": "Desde",
            "toLabel": "Hasta",
            "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Lu",
                "Ma",
                "Mi",
                "Ju",
                "Vi",
                "Sa",
                "Do"
            ],
            "monthNames": [
                "Enero",
                "Febrero",
                "Marzo",
                "Abril",
                "Mayo",
                "Junio",
                "Julio",
                "Agosto",
                "Septiembre",
                "Octubre",
                "Noviembre",
                "Diciembre"
            ],
            "firstDay": 0
        },
        // opens: 'left'
    }, function (start, end, label) {
        $(".calendar-box").html(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY') + " <i class='fas fa-minus'></i> " + end.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
    });
    
    $('.calendar-box').data('daterangepicker').show();
    $('.calendar-box').data('daterangepicker').hide = function () { };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<div class="calendar-box"></div>
```

Por último, sería conveniente que eliminaras esto de tu CSS para evitar que muestre la flecha pequeña que sale arriba a la izquierda (yo estoy tirando del CSS del CDN y no puedo modificarlo):

```
.daterangepicker:before, .daterangepicker:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Kiko_L, utilizaré este apaño. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La librería de daterangepicker maneja una funcionalidad en sus componentes que es la siguiente:

```
 .toggle()
```

La cual la puedes implementar de la siguiente manera:

```
$(".showCalendar").toggle(function() {
    $("#tuInputDate").datepicker("show");
}, function() {
    $("#tuInputDate").datepicker("hide");
});
```

También podrías manejar la propiedad visible para el widget, algo así:

```
$(".dp-icon").click(function (event) {
    var visible = $(".has-dp").datepicker("widget").is(":visible");
    $(".has-dp").datepicker(visible ? "hide" : "show");
})
```

Comment: Hola David, si bien la respuesta puede ser correcta, lo ideal es esperar a que el OP ponga su código para adecuar mejor la respuesta a dicho código.

Comment: Lo que busco es mantener estático el calendario sin que se oculte en ningún caso. He probado lo que me has sugerido pero el botón de fecha se oculta y no veo que solucione mi problema. De todas formas muchas gracias.